# Does this guassian elimination have a solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I was asked to find the following solutions using guassian elimination, but I was unsure of my answers since it became quite messy but the variables still somehow fit:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
3&4&1&7\\
0&1&3&7\\
3&3&-1&9\\
1&2&3&8
\end{array}\right]$$

$$\begin{align*}
&r_1\leftarrow r_1\\
&r_2\leftarrow r_2\\
&r_3\leftarrow r_3-1.5r_1\\
&r_4\leftarrow r_4
\end{align*}$$

Using the above process:

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
2&4&1&7\\
0&1&3&7\\
0&-3&-2.5&-1.5\\
1&2&-3&8
\end{array}\right]$$

$$\begin{align*}
&r_1\leftarrow r_1\\
&r_2\leftarrow r_2\\
&r_3\leftarrow r_3-3r_4\\
&r_4\leftarrow r_4-0.5r_1
\end{align*}$$

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
2&4&1&7\\
0&1&3&7\\
0&-3&-2.5&-1.5\\
0&0&2.5&4.5
\end{array}\right]$$

$$\begin{align*}
&r_1\leftarrow r_1\\
&r_2\leftarrow r_2\\
&r_3\leftarrow r_3+3r_2\\
&r_4\leftarrow r_4-\frac{r_3}{2.6}&\text{unsure about this step}
\end{align*}$$

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
2&4&1&7\\
0&1&3&7\\
0&0&6.5&19.5\\
0&0&0&-3
\end{array}\right]$$

I'm unsure about this last step, am I on the right track here?

Comment: Holy cats.  Could you try to put this into MathJax, I can't even begin to read this.
generic mathjax stuff: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference ; matrices: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5023/167895

Comment: ...from what little I see here, I get the impression you have four equations in three unknowns.  This... generally doesn't work out; you need exactly as many equations as unknowns to make something that has a solution most of the time.

Comment: Please check to see that I transcribed your work correctly. If I did, your matrices don’t altogether match the operations that you said that you were performing; you might want to check your arithmetic.

Comment: @Dan: The original, accessed by clicking on `edit`, was actually fairly readable. What people don’t realize is that long breaks disappear.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, thank you for the edit